# How to convert fee_estimates.dat into a human-readable format?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, fee-estimation

I would like to take a look inside `fee_estimates.dat` to understand a bit better how the RPC command `estimatesmartfee` works. However, when I open the file in a text editor, the content is not readable.

Is there a way to read the information inside `fee_estimates.dat`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at how `fee_estimates.dat` is written and interpreted. It is a binary file composed of:

```
MIN_VERSION
CURRENT_VERSION
CURRENT_TIP
TIP_AT_LAST_START
TIP_AT_LAST_STOP
[ESTIMATES]
[STATS]
```

With `CURRENT` being "when writing", i.e. when stopping `bitcoind`.

[Here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/593f5e239f277e3fd917737122c2aed3c615430c/src/policy/fees.cpp#L864) is the method writing the file, and [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/593f5e239f277e3fd917737122c2aed3c615430c/src/policy/fees.cpp#L889) is the method reading this file (at startup). I think the latter can help you to parse it.