# How can I force estimatesmartfee to return estimates on regtest?

Tags: transaction-fees, regtest

Creating an app that utilizes estimatesmartfee, and it works in production, but I use regtest for automated testing and can't get it to return a value.

Looking at bitcoind tests it is splitting UTXOs in a loop etc.

What is the bare minimum I need to do as far as dummy transactions and mining blocks in order to get estimatesmartfee to work like it does on mainnet.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error message that you get? Or are you getting a constant recommendation at 1 sat/B? I am guessing you need more than 1 vMB of pending transactions

Comment: Question related to my unanswered question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84983/how-to-convert-fee-estimates-dat-into-a-human-readable-format

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill up the mempool of your regtest nodes and mine blocks (this means creating transactions --eg by using `sendtoaddress`-- and generating blocks --with `generatoaddress`).

For reference [here is](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/functional/feature_fee_estimation.py) how it's done to test `estimatesmartfee`.